# Postfix: Outgoing Email Filter + Deliver sent email to a folder

Tags: postfix, dovecot

I'm running a filter for incoming email on Postfix that basically sends the email through SpamAssassin and then delivers it to the user by using `dovecot-lda`.

This is happening by editing Postfix's `master.cf` as follows:

```
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd -o 

content_filter=spamassassin
    spamassassin unix -     n   n   -   -   pipe
        flags=DROhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/bin/spamc -f -e 
        /usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -f ${sender} -d ${user}@${nexthop}
```

With this in mind, is there a way I can set a similar filter to outgoing email that will use `dovecot-lda` to place a copy of all sent email on the `Sent` folder?

I know that placing emails on the `Sent`folder is usually work for the email client, however this causes bandwidth usage duplication since email clients have to sent the email over SMTP and then again over IMAP to the `Sent` folder... And I also have other specific reasons like PHP scripts sending email to want this.

The ideia is:

- Email client sends email over SMTP
- Outgoing email filter "catches" the email and uses `dovecot-lda` to deliver a copy to the `Sent`folder (like I do on receiving);
- Postfix does whatever next he needs to do (send the email to a remover server?).

**Note**: This should be compatible with mail submission on port 587, meaning it should first add all the headers and make sure the email is ok and then get filtered and deliver to `Sent` folder... etc.

Thank you.